# select * from (select count(*) from table)

Tags: sql, select

table : instalation

```
+ id    + id_city   +   name    + sts   +
-------------------------------------------
+ 1     +   1       +   jerry   +   1   +
+ 2     +   1       +   david   +   0   +
+ 3     +   2       +   will    +   1   +
+ 4     +   3       +   nanda   +   2   +
+ 5     +   3       +   maya    +   0   +
+ 6     +   4       +   maya    +   2   +
```

instractions from sts column

```
0 --> pending
1 --> success
2 --> fail
```

table : city

```
+ id_city   +   nm_city     +
-----------------------------
+   1       +   california  +
+   2       +   alaska      +
+   3       +   colorado    +
+   4       +   georgia     +
+   5       +   hawaii      +
+   6       +   lowa        +
```

I want to add rows from table installation combined  with city table,the following table desired result

```
+   nm_city     + id_city   +   suc + fail  +   pending +
----------------------------------------------------------
+   california  +   1       +   2   +   0   +   1
+   alaska      +   2       +   1   +   0   +   0
+   colorado    +   3       +   0   +   1   +   1
+   georgia     +   4       +   0   +   1   +   0
```

I have tried using the following query but the sum for SUC column,FAIL and PENDING does not fit

```
select * from
(select w.nm_city,i.id_city from installation i join city w on i.id_city=w.id_city group by i.id_city) WIL,
(select count(*) as suc from installation where sts=1) SUC,
(select count(*) as fail from installation where sts=2) FAIL,
(select count(*) as pen from installation where sts=0) PEN
```

please help me

Comment: I replaced the extraneous database tags with the generic SQL.  Feel free to add the correct database.

Comment: Ha! 3 equivalent answers.

Comment: Your data sample is incomplete or incorrect. 6 cities and 7 in result. In result California should have 1 - success and 1 pending

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with sum + case:

```
SELECT
    w.nm_city,
    i.id_city,
    sum(case when sts = 1 then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when sts = 2 then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when sts = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM installation i
JOIN city w
    ON i.id_city = w.id_city
GROUP BY i.id_city
```

Btw. Your cities are not cities, those are states.

Answer (score 0):

You need SUM over CASE:

```
SELECT
        i.id_city,
        w.nm_city,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sts=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as pending,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sts=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as success,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sts=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as fail
    FROM
        installation I
        JOIN city W ON i.id_city = w.id_city
    GROUP BY
        i.id_city,
        w.nm_city
```

Although this must work in mysql and sql-server. in future please specify your DBMS directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.id_city, c.nm_city,
   SUM(sts=0) AS pending,
   SUM(sts=1) AS success,
   SUM(sts=2) AS fail
FROM city c
JOIN instalation i
  ON c.id_city = i.id_city
GROUP BY id_city, nm_city
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb5338/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ id_city  ║  nm_city    ║ pending  ║ success  ║ fail ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════╣
║       1  ║ california  ║       1  ║       1  ║    0 ║
║       2  ║ alaska      ║       0  ║       1  ║    0 ║
║       3  ║ colorado    ║       1  ║       0  ║    1 ║
║       4  ║ georgia     ║       0  ║       0  ║    1 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

Original question was tagged by `MySQL` and answer is for MySQL. If it should work on different RDBMS use `CASE` statement.